# Нумерация для каждого div с одинаковым именем класса

Tags: jquery

Есть код (приведу ниже). Он проверяет все `div-ы` с `class="number"` и задает им нумерацию. Но он заменяет весь текст в `div` на цифру нумерации. Как оставить текст в диве, что бы нумерация была перед текстом, типа: `1. Какой то текст` ?

```
jQuery('.number').html(function(i){ return i+1 });
```

Comment: Потому что Вы используете [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) который в данном случае собственно, то и делает, что заменяет контент внутри элемента. Используйте [.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: Спасибо, все верно. Можете дать ответ, я приму )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) работает таким образом что либо возвращает либо изменяет html-содержимое выбранных элементов. В Вашем случае Вы заменяете контент внутри `div` с классом `number` на цифру из нумерации.

Для того чтобы вставить необходимую Вам цифру перед контентом, используйте [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) который добавит контент внутрь выбранных элементов перед существующим контентом.